# How to do Poisson regression in gnuplot

Tags: regression, gnuplot, poisson

I measured the spectrum of an X-ray tube with a Geiger counter. Such data aren't normally distributed, but instead they follow the [Poisson distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution). I want to fit a curve to the measured data:

```
a = 1
b = 1
f(x) = a*(x/b - 1)/x**2
fit f(x) 'data.txt' via a,b
```

This will, however, perform the least-squares regression, which is theoretically wrong in this case. Instead  I need to perform the [Poisson regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_regression). How do I achieve this?

The [link function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_linear_model#Link_function) of the Poisson distribution is ln(*μ*). Is there a way to use this information, eg. with the gnuplot's [link command](http://www.gnuplot.info/docs_5.2/Gnuplot_5.2.pdf#page=143&zoom=auto,-187,362)?